# How can i calculate the value(s) of which some are double?

Tags: java

The code I wrote compiles well, but there are certain values that do not calculate. The rate and hours value, tuition and .08 do not calculate. Maybe my code is wrong or something. I am still new to java so i am trying my best. Here is my code:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.text.DecimalFormat;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Tuition
{
    static double fees;
    static double rate;
    static double tuition;
    private static Scanner sc;
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
    {
        //declare variables
        int hours;

        //call methods
        displayWelcome();
    hours = getHours();
    rate = getRate(hours);
    tuition = calcTuition(hours, rate);
    fees = calcFees(tuition);
}

public static void displayWelcome()
{

    //welcome statement
    System.out.println("Welcome to school that offers distance learning courses");
}

public static int getHours()
{
    //declare method variables
    int hours = 0;

    //a user must enter a string value
    System.out.println("Enter total number of hours");
    sc = new Scanner(System.in);

    try
    {
        hours = sc.nextInt();
    }
    catch(NumberFormatException e)
    {
        System.out.print("Incorrect number");
    }
    return hours;
}

public static double getRate(int hours)
{
    if (hours > 15)
    {
        System.out.println("rate per credit hour is 44.50");
    }
    else
    {
        System.out.println("rate per credit hour is 50.00");
    }
    return rate;
}

public static double calcTuition(int hours, double rate)
    {
        tuition =(double)rate * hours;
        System.out.print("tuition is" + (tuition));
        return tuition;
    }

public static double calcFees(double tuition)
    {
        fees =(double)tuition * .08;
        System.out.print("fees are" + (fees));
        return fees;
    }

public static void displayToatal(double total)
    {
        DecimalFormat twoDigits = new DecimalFormat("$#,000.00");

        System.out.println("the total value is"+ twoDigits.format(tuition + fees));
    }
```

}

Comment: what do you mean "do not calculate" ?

Comment: @deKajoo   they give a 0.0 value

Answer (score 0):

In `calcTuition()`

```
tuition =(double)rate * hours;
```

should be

```
tuition =rate * (double)hours;
```

: )

Comment: But ***why***? Saying *what* without *why* isn't very useful.

Comment: @deKajoo,  nah it still doesnt calculate, rate should be double, not hours. hours is an int

Comment: Well you are casting a double to double where you want to cast the int to double in order to have * operation to return a double
But i supposed this was just a mistake.

Comment: Well it seems that you have understand how cast works, rate is already a double but hours is indeed an int that should be catsed to double so that the * operation understand that it must do an operation between two double an so return a double

Comment: Brendan Goggin answer should solve your issue but you should do the modification I suggested too else the result of calcTuition() will always be round numbers.

Answer (score 0):

You aren't setting the rate. You need a line of code that looks like "rate = x;". You only have println's in the getRate method, but you don't actually set the variable to equal anything.

Comment: you are correct, should have set the value of the rate. ola!